# How to have a CSS transition on an image return to the initial state after mouse removal with a text paragraph above the image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to have my CSS transition, when you after you hover over one of the images and your mouse leaves, return to the position without the hover over a time period of .6 seconds. I've seen a couple of solutions to this problem, but they haven't worked due to the paragraph above each image. You can see some of these images if you scroll to the right, or click on one of the images to have a CSS animation occur. Let me know if you guys need any more information. I'm new to programming and would love any help. Thanks

```js
var click = 0;
function checkClicks(imgs) {

 if(click == 0) {
    // Run your animation on first click
    document.getElementById('column1').classList.add('animate1')
    document.getElementById('column2').classList.add('animate2')
    document.getElementById('column3').classList.add('animate3')
 document.getElementById('column4').classList.add('animate4')
 document.getElementById('column5').classList.add('animate5')
 document.getElementById('column6').classList.add('animate6')
 document.getElementById('column7').classList.add('animate7')
 document.getElementById('column8').classList.add('animate8')
 document.getElementById('column9').classList.add('animate9');
    // hold Images for 1s
  setTimeout(function(){ 
   myFunction(imgs);
  }, 2000);
 } else {
  myFunction(imgs);
 }

 click = 1;
}
function myFunction(imgs) {

 var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
 expandImg.src = imgs.src;
 var imgParagraph = document.getElementById('img-paragraph');
 imgParagraph.innerHTML = imgs.getAttribute("head");

 expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "table-cell";
   imgParagraph.style.display = 'table-cell';
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  src: url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'tekoregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'poppinsmedium';
  src: url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  font-weight: 900;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 21px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  position: relative;
  left: 2%;
}

.topnav a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.topnav a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.topnav a.active-menu:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
  background-color:#EEF0FC;
}
.column p {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.column p {
  transition: top .6s;
  transition-duration: .6s;
  top: 0;
}
.column:hover p {
  opacity:1;
  top:-7px;
  height:100%;
 }

.column p {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.column img {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color:black;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.column:hover img {
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  position: relative; 
  top: -7px;
  transition-duration:  .6s;
}

#totalbody {
  background-color: #EEF0FC;
  height: 600px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* The expanding image container */

#expandedImg {
  position: absolute;
  height:400px;
  left:300px;
  border-radius:10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  top: 320px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-height: 430px;
}


/* Expanding image text */


/* image paragraph */

#img-paragraph {
  display: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 7px;
  float: right;
  right: 30px;
  top: 120px;
}

#expanded-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Closable button inside the expanded image */

.row {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
}

.head1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head3 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head4 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head5 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head6 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head7 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head8 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head9 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}


.head1::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head2::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head3::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head4::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head5::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head6::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head7::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head8::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head9::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.para1{
  width: 90%;
  position: relative;
  left: 6%;
  font-size: 17px;
  top: 60px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
}
#column1 {
  position: absolute;
  width:250px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  top:30px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate1 {
  -webkit-animation: animate1 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate1 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate1 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      position: absolute;
      top: 500px;
      left:300px;

  }
}
@keyframes animate1 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      position: absolute;
      top: 500px;
      left:300px;
  }
}
#column2 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:350px;
  top:50px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate2 {
  -webkit-animation: animate2 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate2 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:50px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:50px;
  }
}
#column3 {
  position: absolute;
  width:260px;
  float:left;
  left:400px;
  top:80px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate3 {
  -webkit-animation: animate3 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate3 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate3 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:600px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate3 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:600px;
  }
}
#column4 {
  position: absolute;
  width:280px;
  float:left;
  left:300px;
  top:80px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate4 {
  -webkit-animation: animate4 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate4 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate4 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 700px;
    left:100px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate4 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 700px;
    left:100px;
  }
}
#column5 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:300px;
  top:80px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate5 {
  -webkit-animation: animate5 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate5 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate5 {
  0% {
    top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:900px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate5 {
  0% {
    top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:900px;
  }
}
#column6 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate6 {
  -webkit-animation: animate6 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate6 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate6 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:500px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate6 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:500px;
  }
}
#column7 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate7 {
  -webkit-animation: animate7 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate7 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate7 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:1000px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate7 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:1000px;
  }
}
#column8 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate8 {
  -webkit-animation: animate8 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate8 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate8 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:200px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate8 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:200px;
  }
}
#column9 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate9 {
  -webkit-animation: animate9 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate9 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate9 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:800px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate9 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:800px;
  }
}
.footer{
  position:relative;
  background-color:rgb(84,104,217);
  height:80px;
  top:546px;
  color:white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.footwords{
  padding-top:32px;
  font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
  position: relative;
  left:6%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1250px) and (min-width: 1150px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: green;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:350px;
    left:262px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
  
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1150px) and (min-width: 1050px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: navy;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:340px;
    left:252px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
  
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1050px) and (min-width: 930px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: brown;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:300px;
    left:228px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 930px) and (min-width: 850px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: magenta;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:270px;
    left:210px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 850px) and (min-width: 800px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:250px;
    left:188px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) and (min-width: 735px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:230px;
    left:178px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 735px) and (min-width: 645px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: moccasin;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:210px;
    left:150px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 645px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="../CSS/styleprojects.css" />
    <script src='../Javascript/script.js'></script>
    <script src='../Javascript/fix.js'></script>
    <script src='../Javascript/jquery-3.5.1.min.js'></script>
    <title>Projects</title>
</head>
<body id='totalbody'>

  <header class="topnav" id="topnav">
    <a class="link" href="../index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="link" href="#Academics">Academics</a>
    <a class="active-menu" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
    <a class="link" href="communityservice.html">Community Service</a>
  </header>

  <div>
    <div id="expanded-wrapper">
      <img id="expandedImg">
      <p id="img-paragraph"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column" id='column1'>
      <img class='arcadeimg' src="../Images/arcade.jpeg" alt="Arcade" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head1'> Parapraph #1 </p><p class='para1'> Lorem ipsum dolor si
        t amet consectetur adipisicing
         elit. Sed natus, recusandae veritatis ipsum quia commodi tenetur laboriosam pariatur nihil incidunt architecto velit so
        luta placeat repellat asperiores iure eos dolorum fugiat?</p>"  onclick="checkClicks(this);">
        <p id='column1p'>this will be shown on the hover 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column2'>
      <img src="../Images/car.png"
        alt="Car" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head2'> Parapraph #2 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
        <p>this will be shown on the hover 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column3'>
      <img src="../Images/pinball.jpeg" alt="Pinball Machine" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head3'> Parapraph #3 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column4'>
      <img src="../Images/vending.jpeg" alt="Vending Machine" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head4'> Parapraph #4 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column5'>
      <img src="../Images/sriraques.jpeg" alt="Sriracha Quesadillas" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head5'> Parapraph #5 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column6'>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTWUVh_Aa4CeLecqvG5L-Xzej1kc1tKwDriiWAVWuUMms5JLHQt&usqp=CAU" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head6'>  web code </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 6</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column7'>
      <img src="https://opticsmag.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/a-telescope.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head7'> computer </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 7</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column8'>
      <img src="https://nctennis.com/common/controls/image_handler.aspx?thumb_id=13&image_path=/images/2018/11/27/Wheelchair.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head8'> adap tennis </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 8</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column9'>
      <img src="https://cdn.britannica.com/77/170477-050-1C747EE3/Laptop-computer.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head9'> telescope </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 9</p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class='footer'>
    <p class='footwords'>
      © 2020 By . Proudly Individually Coded.
    </p>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What css code handles the transition in question?

Comment: I suggest in future you only add the relevant code that is in question. It helps others to hone in on your issue quicker and more efficiently.

Comment: Will do in the future, but the code that affects the transition are .column:hover img & .column:hover p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need a transition `ease-out` with the duration on the non-hover css code... Check out my snippit and see if that does the trick

**Edit:** OP asked if a fade could be placed on his text that shows when hovering over an image. The text has pointer-events disabled to be able to click through to the image below so an event listener may not work. I have combined the two CSS selectors `.column p` into one selector and added `transition: all .6s ease-out` just below the `opacity` and `top` properties. This will add the transition to both the `top` and `opacity` after returning from hover state.

CSS:

```
.column p {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .6s ease-out;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.column:hover p { 
  opacity: 1; 
  top:-7px;
  transition: all .6s ease-out;
  height:100%;
 }
```

```js
var click = 0;
function checkClicks(imgs) {
  
 if(click == 0) {
    // Run your animation on first click
    document.getElementById('column1').classList.add('animate1')
    document.getElementById('column2').classList.add('animate2')
    document.getElementById('column3').classList.add('animate3')
 document.getElementById('column4').classList.add('animate4')
 document.getElementById('column5').classList.add('animate5')
 document.getElementById('column6').classList.add('animate6')
 document.getElementById('column7').classList.add('animate7')
 document.getElementById('column8').classList.add('animate8')
 document.getElementById('column9').classList.add('animate9');
    // hold Images for 1s
  setTimeout(function(){ 
   myFunction(imgs);
  }, 2000);
 } else {
  myFunction(imgs);
 }

 click = 1;
}
function myFunction(imgs) {
 var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
 expandImg.src = imgs.src;
 var imgParagraph = document.getElementById('img-paragraph');
 imgParagraph.innerHTML = imgs.getAttribute("head");

 expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "table-cell";
   imgParagraph.style.display = 'table-cell';
}
let target = document.querySelector('.column img');
target.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => document.querySelector('.column p').style.opacity = '0');
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  src: url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'tekoregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'poppinsmedium';
  src: url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  font-weight: 900;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 21px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  position: relative;
  left: 2%;
}

.topnav a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.topnav a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.topnav a.active-menu:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
  background-color:#EEF0FC;
}

.column p {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .6s ease-out;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.column:hover p { 
  opacity: 1; 
  top:-7px;
  transition: all .6s ease-out;
  height:100%;
 } 

.column img {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color:black;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  transition: all .6s ease-out;
}

.column:hover img {
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  position: relative; 
  top: -7px;
  transition: all .6s ease-in;
}

#totalbody {
  background-color: #EEF0FC;
  height: 600px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* The expanding image container */

#expandedImg {
  position: absolute;
  height:400px;
  left:300px;
  border-radius:10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  top: 320px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-height: 430px;
}


/* Expanding image text */


/* image paragraph */

#img-paragraph {
  display: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 7px;
  float: right;
  right: 30px;
  top: 120px;
}

#expanded-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Closable button inside the expanded image */

.row {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
}

.head1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head3 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head4 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head5 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head6 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head7 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head8 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head9 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}


.head1::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head2::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head3::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head4::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head5::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head6::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head7::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head8::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head9::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.para1{
  width: 90%;
  position: relative;
  left: 6%;
  font-size: 17px;
  top: 60px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
}
#column1 {
  position: absolute;
  width:250px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  top:30px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate1 {
  -webkit-animation: animate1 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate1 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate1 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      position: absolute;
      top: 500px;
      left:300px;

  }
}
@keyframes animate1 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      position: absolute;
      top: 500px;
      left:300px;
  }
}
#column2 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:350px;
  top:50px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate2 {
  -webkit-animation: animate2 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate2 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:50px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:50px;
  }
}
#column3 {
  position: absolute;
  width:260px;
  float:left;
  left:400px;
  top:80px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate3 {
  -webkit-animation: animate3 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate3 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate3 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:600px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate3 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:600px;
  }
}
#column4 {
  position: absolute;
  width:280px;
  float:left;
  left:300px;
  top:80px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate4 {
  -webkit-animation: animate4 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate4 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate4 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 700px;
    left:100px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate4 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 700px;
    left:100px;
  }
}
#column5 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:300px;
  top:80px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate5 {
  -webkit-animation: animate5 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate5 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate5 {
  0% {
    top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:900px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate5 {
  0% {
    top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:900px;
  }
}
#column6 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate6 {
  -webkit-animation: animate6 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate6 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate6 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:500px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate6 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:500px;
  }
}
#column7 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate7 {
  -webkit-animation: animate7 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate7 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate7 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:1000px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate7 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:1000px;
  }
}
#column8 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate8 {
  -webkit-animation: animate8 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate8 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate8 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:200px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate8 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:200px;
  }
}
#column9 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate9 {
  -webkit-animation: animate9 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate9 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate9 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:800px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate9 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:800px;
  }
}
.footer{
  position:relative;
  background-color:rgb(84,104,217);
  height:80px;
  top:546px;
  color:white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.footwords{
  padding-top:32px;
  font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
  position: relative;
  left:6%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1250px) and (min-width: 1150px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: green;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:350px;
    left:262px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
  
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1150px) and (min-width: 1050px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: navy;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:340px;
    left:252px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
  
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1050px) and (min-width: 930px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: brown;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:300px;
    left:228px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 930px) and (min-width: 850px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: magenta;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:270px;
    left:210px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 850px) and (min-width: 800px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:250px;
    left:188px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) and (min-width: 735px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:230px;
    left:178px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 735px) and (min-width: 645px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: moccasin;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:210px;
    left:150px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 645px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="../CSS/styleprojects.css" />
    <script src='../Javascript/script.js'></script>
    <script src='../Javascript/fix.js'></script>
    <script src='../Javascript/jquery-3.5.1.min.js'></script>
    <title>Projects</title>
</head>
<body id='totalbody'>



  <div>
    <div id="expanded-wrapper">
      <img id="expandedImg">
      <p id="img-paragraph"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column" id='column1'>
      <img class='arcadeimg' src="../Images/arcade.jpeg" alt="Arcade" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head1'> Parapraph #1 </p><p class='para1'> Lorem ipsum dolor si
        t amet consectetur adipisicing
         elit. Sed natus, recusandae veritatis ipsum quia commodi tenetur laboriosam pariatur nihil incidunt architecto velit so
        luta placeat repellat asperiores iure eos dolorum fugiat?</p>"  onclick="checkClicks(this);">
        <p id='column1p'>this will be shown on the hover 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column2'>
      <img src="../Images/car.png"
        alt="Car" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head2'> Parapraph #2 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
        <p>this will be shown on the hover 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column3'>
      <img src="../Images/pinball.jpeg" alt="Pinball Machine" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head3'> Parapraph #3 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column4'>
      <img src="../Images/vending.jpeg" alt="Vending Machine" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head4'> Parapraph #4 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column5'>
      <img src="../Images/sriraques.jpeg" alt="Sriracha Quesadillas" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head5'> Parapraph #5 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column6'>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTWUVh_Aa4CeLecqvG5L-Xzej1kc1tKwDriiWAVWuUMms5JLHQt&usqp=CAU" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head6'>  web code </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 6</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column7'>
      <img src="https://opticsmag.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/a-telescope.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head7'> computer </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 7</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column8'>
      <img src="https://nctennis.com/common/controls/image_handler.aspx?thumb_id=13&image_path=/images/2018/11/27/Wheelchair.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head8'> adap tennis </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 8</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column9'>
      <img src="https://cdn.britannica.com/77/170477-050-1C747EE3/Laptop-computer.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head9'> telescope </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 9</p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class='footer'>
    <p class='footwords'>
      © 2020 By . Proudly Individually Coded.
    </p>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible to get it so the opacity and the words also ease out?

Comment: What code block are you talking about? `.column p`?

Comment: When you hover over the image (and the text appeares), i've previously tried to use the ease out for when the text appears (so the and opacity slowly disappears), but it didn't work.

Comment: So you want the p tag that sits on top of the image to `ease-out` (animate) it's display to none in .6 seconds as well?

Comment: Yes, use animation with @keyframe event-> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes. I have added to the snippit as well. Play around with the % to get your desired fade...

Comment: Had to remove the header section as your post exceeds the limit on characters allowed in a post... `30,000` Does not matter though as the functionality is still there to test with the hover. BTW, the css code I entered is @ `.column:hover p`, then the `@keyframe` waypoints READ ME: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations

Comment: I think your missing part of what I was saying. I was trying to get it so after the mouse leaves the image (and the hover is no longer taking place), the opacity and text fade away over a .6 second period instead of instantly. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: OK, I see what you're looking for. See if my edit does the trick.

Comment: That's Perfect. Thank you